# Javascript implementation of WS-I Reliable Secure Profile

Tags: javascript, comet, reverse-ajax, reliable-secure-profile, ws-i

I'm using the .NET 4 [server side implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818238.aspx) of [Reliable Secure Profile](http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/workinggroup.aspx?wg=reliablesecure) for HTTP/S push and want to know if there is a JavaScript client available.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are [several generic SOAP libraries](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enSE506SE506&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=sv&gs_rn=2&gs_ri=serp&tok=oj8fIpiHjXvIm81zkY-KyQ&pq=ws-i%20javascript&cp=13&gs_id=2e&xhr=t&q=javascript%20SOAP%20library&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&tbo=d&rlz=1C5CHFA_enSE506SE506&sclient=psy-ab&oq=javascript%20SO&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b59300f84aec075e&ion=1&biw=1751&bih=1087) to talk to web services but not one that is specifically geared towards WS-I or the RSP definition.

It might make for a good open source project though. Please add info here if you start it up, others might like it :)